# Saxon 6.5.5 jar file will work in android 4.2.2 for XML parser

Tags: saxon

Saxon 6.5.5 will work in android 4.2.2?

I observed that the some API name in saxon 6.5.5 jar file is the same as the standard android API.

How to resolve API conflict and use the class available in saxon 6.5.5 jar instead of the available with android API.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon 6.5.5 was produced a very long time ago, probably before Android appeared on the scene. It isn't tested or supported on Android. It's possible that someone has got it to work (it's open source code after all), but that's not something I'm aware of.

We did have an attempt to get a much more recent release of Saxon to work on Android. I don't think the problems looked insuperable, but we didn't complete the project.

As regards APIs, you're probably referring to the JAXP API (e.g. `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory`. That's a standard Java interface for invoking XSLT transformations; there have been a number of implementations of this interface over the years but the two that are widely used are Saxon and Xalan. The mechanisms for selecting an implementation of `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` are described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8//docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html